# Error with form.non_field_errors are not displayed

Tags: django

I try show errors without `fieldname` identifier. For this i run in template `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. But error not displayed. If i run with `form.errors` the erros are displayed, but with `fieldname` too, it's not what i want.

I use `AbstractBaseUser` like:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = u'Nome',
        max_length=33
    )
    #identifier
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name = u'Email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = u'telefone',
        max_length=12
    )
    #...
```

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=False,
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Nome',
                'autocomplete':'off',
                }
    ))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=False,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}
    ))
    email_confirmation = forms.EmailField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Confirme o email',
                'id': 'email_confirmation',
                'class': 'input cemail-cad'
                }
    ))
    phone = forms.CharField(
        label=False,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Telefone'}
    ))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=False,
        max_length=50,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Senha'}
    ))
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=False,
        max_length=50,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirme sua senha'}
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_username(self):
        # mínimo 2 caracteres máximo 150 caracteres
        if not re.compile(r'^\S*[\w\.\-\_\d]{3,150}').match(str(self)):
            raise ValidationError("Nome inválido: Mínimo 3 caracteres, somente letras, números e '.', '-' ou '_' especiais")
    
    def clean_email(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignupForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_confirmation = cleaned_data.get('email_confirmation')

        if email != email_confirmation:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email diferente")
        
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email já exite')

    def clean_phone(self):

        if not re.compile(r'([0-9]{2})([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4})').match(str(self)):
            raise ValidationError("Telefone inválido: 00-00000-0000 somente números com DDD ")
```

views.py

```
class SignupView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    
    template_name = 'admin/signup.html'
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect(to='/confirma-conta/')
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

templates/admin/signup.html

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <ul class="alert"><li>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</li></ul>
{% endif %}
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.email }}
{{ form.email_confirmation }}
{{ form.phone }}
{{ form.password1 }}
{{ form.password2 }}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('criar-conta/', SignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    #...
]
```

What is need to or how `form.non_field_errors` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Form.non_field_errors()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors) should give you a list of errors:

```html
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```